# Trouble with VBA loop and if/else statements

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a loop with multiple if/else statements to work but it keeps saying either I have Ifs with no End Ifs or that I have a Loop with no Do.

Any pointers would be great.

Below is the what I've done so far, please go easy on me I only started trying to write in vba yesterday...

```
Sub EditTransposeCopy()

Sheets("Altered").Select

Dim count As Long
count = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A6", Range("A6").End(xlDown))) - 1

Do While count > 0
If InStr(1, (Range("A23").Value), "Reason:") > 0 Then
    Rows("9:11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("16").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("18").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A7:A18").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A6:N6").Copy
    Sheets("Output").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Altered").Select
    Rows("6:18").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    count = count - 19
Else
    If InStr(1, (Range("A20").Value), "Reason:") > 0 Then
    Rows("9:11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("16").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A7:A16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A6:L6").Copy
    Sheets("Output").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Altered").Select
    Rows("6:16").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    count = count - 16
Else
    If InStr(1, (Range("A17").Value), "Reason:") > 0 Then
    Rows("9:11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Rows("14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A7:A14").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A6:J6").Copy
    Sheets("Output").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Altered").Select
    Rows("6:14").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    count = count - 13
Else
    If InStr(1, (Range("A15").Value), "£0.00") > 0 Then
    Sheets("Altered").Select
    Rows("9:11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A7:A12").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C6").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A6:H6").Copy
    Sheets("Output").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Altered").Select
    Rows("6:12").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    count = count - 10
Else
    count = count - 10000000
End If
Loop

'
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ElseIf` or terminate each `If` block with an `End If`

```
Sub EditTransposeCopy()

'...

Do While count > 0
    If InStr(1, (Range("A23").Value), "Reason:") > 0 Then
        '...
    ElseIf InStr(1, (Range("A20").Value), "Reason:") > 0 Then
        '...
    ElseIf InStr(1, (Range("A15").Value), "£0.00") > 0 Then
        '...
    Else
        '...
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Please, don't put answers on SO for VBA/Excel that uses `Select` and `Selection`.

Comment: Awesome thanks, it works now. I got rid of the select options too!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, and welcome to VBA!

First up, you should look at [how to avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), because although this is how the macro recorder works, it's better practice (less prone to bugs) and more readable if you replace code like

```vba
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
```

with

```vba
Range("A1").Copy
```

Secondly look up the [syntax of an `if` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements) - in particular [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements) about use of `Else If` will be handy in the above code. Each `If` requires it's own `End If`, looks like you missed a couple in your original code.

Comment: Thanks. So with regards to not using select should my first if block look more like this    If InStr(1, (Range("A23").Value), "Reason:") > 0 Then
        Rows("9:11").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("14").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("16").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Rows("18").Delete Shift:=xlUp
        Range("A7:A18").Copy
        Range("C6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
        Range("A6:N6").Copy
        Sheets("Output").Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: I can't get this write the code nicely...oh the shame

Comment: Got it all sorted and now the code is half as long! Thanks again for your help